# Get Unique record from one list that not match with other?

Tags: c#, list

Hi I have two list I want to get Unique record from first list that not match with other.

Example

List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
List = [1,2,3,4,5,8]

According to my need output should be like this [6,7].

Please suggest me how it will be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<int> result = list1.Except(list2);
```